# Make the contents of a perforce directory exactly match the latest depot version

Tags: perforce

I would like to make the contents of a directory in a Perforce workspace be exactly the same as the latest depot contents. I want this to work no matter what has gone on in the workspace.  (For example, editing files without opening them in perforce, creating unsubmitted changesets, etc.)

So far I have come up with running this series of commands, in order:

```
p4 clean ...
p4 revert ...
p4 sync ...
```

Will this do what I want?  Is this the correct order? Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the correct commands, and you do need all three:

- `revert` is needed to discard changes to files you've opened
- `clean` is needed to discard changes to files you haven't opened (including added files)
- `sync` is needed to make sure you're at the very latest depot revision

You should either put `clean` after the `revert` or add `-w` to `revert`; otherwise files that were opened for add will be skipped by the `clean` (because they're open) and then `revert` will "abandon" them in the workspace (the `-w` option causes `revert` to delete/"wipe" added files instead of abandoning them).  Other than that, I think the order is unimportant.